# Get; Set; Variables

Tags: c#, variables, methods, get

I'm setting up multiple methods and wondering how to continue to pass one variable (The "top" variable) to different methods.

Main method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] anArray = new int[5];
        int top = -1;
        PushPeek(anArray);
```

then I need to pass top to:

```
public static void PushPeek(int[] ar)
    {

        if (ar[ar.Length -1] == ar.Length -1)
        {
            //do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            top = top + 1;
            Console.WriteLine(ar[top]);
        }
    }\
```

I know it involves something with get; set; but I don't know how, any help?

Answer (score 2):

Pass it by reference:

```
public static void PushPeek(int[] ar, ref int top)
{
    ...
}

int[] anArray = new int[5];
int top = -1;
PushPeek(anArray, ref top);
```

Comment: This will eventually be a stack class with push pop and peek things and I assume that the top variable will consistently be changing, won't that require me to use a get;?

Comment: What you call "get; set;" is called a property. But in you case, you just need top to be a field of your class (i.e. a variable of the class)

Comment: Right, but I also need to be able to change it in different methods then go back to the first method and use the same variable with the updated variable. Will this work for it?

Comment: Will I have to take void out and return top?

Answer (score 0):

All about properties: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Auto-implemented properties are awesome! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx